# What does it mean to copy a command to a different name?

Tags: sudo

> Limitations of the ‘!’ operator
>
> It is generally not effective to “subtract” commands from ALL using
> the ‘!’ operator. A user can trivially circumvent this by copying the
> desired command to a different name and then executing that. For
> example:
>
> bill  ALL = ALL, !SU, !SHELLS
>
> Doesn't really prevent bill from running the commands listed in SU or
> SHELLS since he can simply copy those commands to a different name, or
> use a shell escape from an editor or other program. Therefore, these
> kind of restrictions should be considered advisory at best (and
> reinforced by policy).
>
> In general, if a user has sudo ALL there is nothing to prevent them
> from creating their own program that gives them a root shell (or
> making their own copy of a shell) regardless of any ‘!’ elements in
> the user specification.

What does the

> he can  simply copy those commands to a different name

mean? Is it command aliasing or something else?

Comment: With ALL in sudoer file, even with exceptions, he still can copy any shell or sudo under another name such as hsab for bash or odus for sudo And provide the necessary rights to execute even with his regular user. ie `cp /usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/hsab` & `chmod u+s /usr/bin/hsab`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands are usually<sup>(*)</sup> files,
and files can be copied under different names.

e.g.

```
$ cp /bin/ls /tmp/lslsls
$ % /tmp/lslsls -l /tmp/lslsls
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ilkkachu  wheel  187040 Dec  5 20:03 /tmp/lslsls
```

Now, if `sudo` allowed me to run anything but `ls` as root, I would still be allowed to run `lslsls`, which now has the exact same contents. Even making the original file execute-only (unreadable) wouldn't be much help, since one can often find another binary that does the equivalent thing. (I once had to use a system where `sudo` was configured to not allow running `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`. But anything else was ok, including running `apt-get`, so I considered just installing zsh.)

<sup>(* shell builtins and functions would be an exception.)</sup>

The man page also mentions using "a shell escape from an editor or other program", which refers to using commands like `:shell` or `:!bash` in vi, or simply `sudo perl -e 'exec "sh"'` or `sudo awk 'BEGIN { system("sh") }'` (in at least GNU AWK). None of those would be caught by the restrictions sudo implements.

Comment: And of course you can run `sudo sh -c ls` or `sudo env ls` or `sudo /lib/ld.so /bin/ls` or `watch ls` or `perl -e 'exec "ls"'`....

Comment: Technically, you can run `sudo -s builtin` to run a builtin (technically that runs a shell to interpret some shell code meant to run the builtin with the given arguments; and you must be authorised to run the shell with any argument for that to work).

Comment: @G-Man, d'oh, yes of course execute-only and not read-only..., thanks

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, right, there's `sudo -s builtin`. Now I'm starting to wonder if it checks access controls based on the shell's name in that case (I hope) and not the name of the builtin... Eh, I'll just ignore that corner case.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't think about that. Thanks!